# Cannot install rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm

Somehow my rails installation hides itself successfully...

I have:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
rvm 1.10.0-pre 
gem 1.8.10
```

and I try to install rails:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

it works fine:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.1.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.3...
```

when I do:

```
rails - v
```

I get

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Also, when I do

```
rake
```

in a rails app root directory, I get:

```
Missing the Rails  gem. Please `gem install -v= rails`, update your 
RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version 
you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the 
latest version installed.
```

executing

```
gem install -v= rails
```

raises an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
Illformed requirement ["="]
```

So apparently it is sitting somewhere and cannot be seen by my environment. I guess installing via apt-get is not an option as I don't want to confuse gem...

Any ideas?
Cheers
Mac

Comment: Show `$PATH`, maybe U don't have there path to Gems' binaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use `sudo`.

Just `gem install rails`

Comment: Specifically the environment used by`sudo` won't have access to RVM and will install the gems in the system `ruby`'s location. With RVM you don't need `sudo` access because all of the files are installed into user-writable areas

Comment: I love it! Thanks, guys - you're brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Use RVM instead of the packaged ruby/gems distribution. http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/